# Simulate 5 die roll for Yahtzee game

Tags: matlab, random, dice

I'm trying to simulate rolling 5 dice for a Yahtzee game I'm writing in MATLAB, but I'm running into the issue that my code doesn't seem to generate any yahtzees after running 1000+ iterations. Am I using a function that will guarantee for a Yahtzee(5 of the same number) to be rolled?

```
while rounds<=13
    fprintf('Rolling the dice...\n');
    roll=randi(6,1,5);
    roll=sort(roll);
    fprintf('You rolled:');
    disp(roll);
    rollCount=rollCount+1;

    for x=rule
        if roll==rule{1};
            fprintf('Condition Met');
            break;
        end
    end
    rounds=rounds+1;

end
```

This basically just iterates through 13 rounds of rolling and checks the roll against "rule{1}" which is an array that contains [1 1 1 1 1]. There doesn't seem to be a problem getting 3, sometimes 4 1s, but I can't get 5. Any suggestions?

Comment: 6^5 is 7776. You should not be expecting a [1 1 1 1 1] result in 1,000 iterations very often.

Comment: Doh. I guess you're right. Wasn't thinking it was that low of a probability. I changed it to 10000 iterations, and I can see it stopping after getting the correct sequence. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan Cavanaugh pointed out, there weren't enough samples being done to catch the wanted result. I upped the simulation to run 10000 times and it works as intended.

Comment: There's also a flaw in your code. You say "if roll==rule{1}", but it needs to be "if roll==x{1}".

Comment: Hmm, if I change that to what you suggest, I get an error "Matrix dimensions must agree." rule is an array of arrays, and roll is an array of the 5 digits. What that for loop is trying to do is step through each of the arrays in rule and see if roll matches it. Could you fix the entire chunk to make it work like that? I'm not sure if my code does that.

Comment: As it stands, your code checks your roll against rule{1} repeatedly, rather than checking against each rule. If you're finding that it complains about matrix dimensions, you should check to see if all of your rules have been entered with the right dimension - that is, that you haven't inserted some as row vectors and some as column vectors.

Also worth checking is whether you need the curly brackets - it might just need to be "if roll==x". I use Octave, which requires the curly bracket index, but I don't know if Matlab does.

Comment: The example code here was just to check and make sure that the rolling was random and that the logic was working for checking against rules. In the final result, it will check against all the rules.

Are you able to explain how I would go about doing so? How to check my roll array against each array in rule? In C++, it would be something like:

    for(int i =0;i<100;i++)
        if (roll==rule[i])
            <DO SOMETHING>

Comment: `for x = 1:5
    if roll == rule{x}` should do it assuming that rule looks like {[1 1 1 1 1], [2 2 2 2 2]...} but it would be easier to just check `if(roll(1) == mean(roll))` as that just checks that all 5 rolls are the same regardless of their value so eliminates the need for the loop